# Linux + how to give only specific user to read the file

Tags: linux, files, permissions, group

lets say we want that only user tutu can read the file

```
/home/grafh/file.txt
```

what is the configuration that need to do in order to enable that?

- file owner must be stay as root  ( and only user tutu can read the file )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two possibilities, using the the classical DAC (Discretionary Access Control, the usual `rwx` rights) of using files ACL (Access Control Lists).

## Using DAC permissions

If *tutu* has not its own group (check `groups tutu` output), you must create a new group and make *tutu* the only member of this group.

```
root@host:~# addgroup tutu
root@host:~# usermod -G tutu tutu
```

Then change the file permissions to allow read access to the members of the *tutu* group:

```
root@host:~# chgrp tutu /home/grafh/file.txt
root@host:~# chmod 640 /home/grafh/file.txt
```

This file will remain owned by *root*, but be readable (but not writeable) by *tutu* and not by the other other users.

## Using ACL permissions

ACLs are additional rights which come in addition to the DAC permissions seen above. There are meant to solve situation which cannot be easily solved using the historical Unix DAC permission system.

To allow *tutu* to read the file:

```
root@host:~# setfacl -m u:tutu:r /home/grafh/file.txt
```

Comment: On Red Hat based systems the command will be groupadd.

Answer (score 3):

In order for this to work `tutu` must have execution access to `/home/grafh`.

`root` must execute these commands:

```
chown root:tutu /home/grafh/file.txt 
chmod 640  /home/grafh/file.txt
```

This works only if there is a group `tutu` and the user `tutu` is its only member.

Comment: I forget to tell you that owner must be stay as root , so we need other solution

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is used in [Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#more-information):

```
$ sudo chmod 400 /home/grafh/file.txt
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/grafh/file.txt
```